# How can I use FQL to count the number of specific pages each friend likes?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Here is an example query:

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id IN (104266592953439, 16155433, 5768707450) 
  AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
```

This will give me the uids of friends who like *either* of the above three pages.

I would like a solution that lets me know how many of the pages within the above subset is liked by each friend (provided they like at least one of them). Something that can scale out to 20+ pages within the subset would be ideal.

For example, if a friend likes all 3 of the pages, listing their uid 3 times would suffice. Although I'm not sure if that is possible in FQL.

Using PHP Facebook SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Graph API doesn't have a `count` method, so you're going to have to do this in your script.

Change your query above to this:

```
SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE page_id IN (104266592953439, 16155433, 5768707450) 
  AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) ORDER BY uid
```

Then loop through your result and count how many times each `uid` appears.